# как передать статус неактивный yii2

Tags: php, yii2

всем привет задам терзающий меня вопрос, есть таблица human с строкой data_okon (с датой окончания) и строкой status,   после как пройдет дата окончания мне надо присвоить значение в строку status неактивный, но если время еще не вышло, или при добавлении новых людей их статус должен быть активным, и все это должно происходить без моего вмешательство

Comment: [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) ?

Comment: мне нужен цикл или условие

Answer (score 0):

Немного расширю ответ от Bookin.
Пишете консольную команду (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html), которая будет проверять дату окончания и менять статус. Скажем она будет вызываться так:

```
./yii check/expiry-date
```

Для этого нужно добавить класс:

```
namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use app\models\Human;

class СheckController extends Controller
{
    public function optionExpiryDate()
    {
        $expiredHumans = Human::find()->where('data_okon <= NOW()')->all();
        foreach($expiredHumans as $human) {
            $human->status = Human::NOT_ACTIVE;
            $human->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Затем нужно регулярно вызывать эту команду. На Linux можно использовать cron. Для этого выполнить:

```
crontab -e
```

И добавить строку для выполнения команды раз в минуту:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/www/site; ./yii check/expiry-date
```

После этого `cron` будет раз в минуту выполнять вашу команду

Comment: куда её добавлять?

Comment: в папку commands, если используется basic template

Comment: как назвать? check?

Comment: назвал Check, вложил то что вы написали, открыл консоль и прописал ./yii check/expiry-date, выводит не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: @nike может по тому что у вас нет в корне файла yii? может стоило бы перейти в папку сайта и там попробовать, только без `./`?

Comment: cd domains/cd sss/ yii check expiry-date тот же результат

Comment: 29 Sep 02:45:00 Start: d:\0000\openserver\modules\php\PHP-7\php-win.exe -c d:\0000\openserver\modules\php\PHP-7\php.ini -q -f d:\0000\openserver\domains\sss.ss\commands\CheckController.php
29 Sep 02:45:00 Start result: 0

Comment: [28-Sep-2017 23:45:01 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'yii\console\Controller' not found in D:\0000\OpenServer\domains\sss.ss\commands\CheckController.php on line 8